# how to load js and css file from web content spring mvc

Tags: javascript, css, spring, model-view-controller, mapping

I am unable to load JS and CSS file from webcontent folder.My login page goes without formatting please suggest me how to load this I am not using maven.
Plz find the image.[image]
[image]

Comment: I believe it should go in the resources folder

Answer (score 1):

1) Create "resources" folder.

2) Add this in your xml file:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

3)"Use" it in your page:

```
<link href="<c:url value="/resources/name_of_file.css" />" rel="stylesheet">
```

If you use Java Config, something like this will do the job:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry
          .addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
          .addResourceLocations("/resources/"); 
    }
}
```